# unable to set style in React Native with props

Tags: javascript, react-native

M starting with React Native and got stuck with a thing.
I am not able to set style by using props.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
    imageStyle : {
        height: 100,
        width: 100
    },
    red: {
        color: 'red',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    green : {
        color: 'green',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    backgroundGrey : {
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    }
})

class ColorfulText extends Component {
    render() {
        var st = this.props.sty;
        var name = this.props.name;
        return ( < Text
        style={Styles.st}> Hi Colorful {name}</Text >);
    }
}

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ColorfulText name="Hanuman" sty="green"/>
            </View>


    );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

the name props works, but the style props doesnot.

I was not able to find the answer so posted here. If this question is duplicate then let me know. i'l remote this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class ColorfulText extends Component {
    render() {
        var st = this.props.sty;
        var name = this.props.name;
        return ( < Text
        style={Styles[st]}> Hi Colorful {name}</Text >);
    }
}
```

You must use the index syntax rather than the dot syntax if you are trying to use the value of a variable to read a property from an object e.g
You wanted `Styles.green` not `Styles.sty`